# C Methods yielding inconsistent results

Tags: c

Firstly I am fairly familar with Java programming and have just started to learn C programming.

Below is a program that takes inputted integers and finds the min, max and sum.

To me (at least) that code written seems logical in properly performing the needed tasks and functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int sum(int array[], unsigned int length) {
    int sumTest;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sumTest = sumTest + array[i];
    }
    return sumTest;
}

int max(int array[], unsigned int length) {
    int maxTest = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxTest) {
            array[i] = maxTest;
        }
    }
    return maxTest;
}

int min(int array[], unsigned int length) {
    int minTest = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < minTest) {
            array[i] = minTest;
        }
    }
    return minTest;
}

int main(void) {


unsigned int length = 0;
    scanf("%u", &length);
    int array[length];
    int temp = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        array[i] = temp;
    }

    printf("SUM: %d\n", sum(array, length));
    printf("MAX: %d\n", max(array, length));
    printf("MIN: %d\n", min(array, length));

    return 0;
}
```

However when I type in the console some entries the results vary every time.

```
1
10
SUM: 286271434
MAX: 10
MIN: 10
```

Again

```
1
10
SUM: -72217974
MAX: 10
MIN: 10
```

My compiler highlights the "<" sign in the for loops in the three methods min,max and sum telling me I am comparing unsigned and signed integers. To fix this I have tried fixing the line to look like this.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

Unfortunately I still get the same results, which logically to me makes sense as I have read that unsigned integers can hold large positive numbers. I've read a bit about C being more about memory management, is it possible that I am not considering memory as a factor. I've truth fully been looking up the syntax from handbooks and forum posts none of which don't seem to consider memory as a factor and which seems no different from java.

Can someone help me understand why this happening and what a solution is.

Thank you.

Comment: 'fairly familar with Java programming' OK, what debugger did you use with java?  You need to use a similar tool with C.  Had you done so, the uninitialized value issue would have become obvious and this question unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ever initialize `sumTest` to anything before using it to keep track of the sum so the value is indeterminate. Setting it to 0 should fix the issue like so:

```
int sum(int array[], unsigned int length) {
    int sumTest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sumTest = sumTest + array[i];
    }
    return sumTest;

}
```

Comment: Thank you that has solved the large sum value. Is there anything obvious wrong with my for loop? It seems to be iterating properly. Problems with unsigned and signed comparisons perhaps?

Comment: In general, you should always compare similar types which is what the compiler is telling you. It's not the cause of the logic error you see, but it could hide several bugs. For example a signed 0xFFFF FFFF is a different value than an unsigned 0xFFFF FFFF.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `sum_test=0;`.

While finding the min/max instead of saving the temp value you modify the array. This should solve it:

`min_test = array[i];`

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have noted, `sumTest` needs to be initialized to 0 before use.

You might also want to test what happens with

```
unsigned int length = 0;
scanf("%u", &length);
int array[length];
```

when you enter a very large value for `length`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the sumTest, so it takes any garbage value. To make it more meaningful initialize it to 0
i.e. int sumTest = 0;